# My rig won't move my character properly

Tags: rigging, unity

I've been working on a character for the past couple of days now, and when creating and parenting my rig, it won't work at all. The rig gets parented, but when I go to pose mode, nothing happens.

I searched online, and most of the other people who have had this problem just needed to go into edit mode for the object that needed to be rigged and merge --> by distance. I've tried this, but it still didn't work.

I am attaching a picture (with the rig NOT parented).

I also want to export this model into Unity.

Here is the link to the file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Rtx86X-QY49MI5FJhlSmCyu7C3ZElxYM?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Please share your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it

Comment: @JohnEason I edited my question to include a link to a Google Drive folder with the file. The file was too big to share through the method you suggested.

Comment: If you look in  the Info editor, you would see several "bone heating" errors. And if you look that error up here on BSE or elsewhere, several solutions are mentioned in addition to removing doubled vertices. One common source of that error is having meshes that are too heavy. You have over a million triangles, that's a lot.

Comment: @L0Lock  How would I get rid of these triangles?

Comment: You can try using Mesh > Cleanup > Limited Dissolve on each object in Edit mode which will reduce the number of vertices to around 113,000. However the model obviously wasn't created in Blender and doing that leaves a very disjointed mesh. Also, it looks as if the "bone heating" errors that @L0Lock mentions are there because the pelvis bones (bone.006.L and bone.006.R) aren't actually connected to the main root bone. I think you'd be better off finding a lower poly model, preferably created in Blender, and then redoing the armature from scratch.

Comment: @JohnEason  I created this model in Blender. I don't really have the time to redo the model from scratch. I'll try the Limited Dissolve thing. How do you view the errors?

Comment: When you parent the rig to the model you'll briefly see an orange error on the bottom status bar. The errors also appear if you go to Window > Toggle System Console.The armature heirarchy in the Outliner shows that those bones aren't connected and in Edit mode you can grab them and move the whole bone around.  The reason I didn't think that your model was created in Blender was because a) it's triangulated, and b) every Edge on the body, T-shirt and trousers is marked Sharp!

Comment: About the lightening of the model (which you should do even if it's not the cause of the weight error, for performance’s sake at least and also have less work to do when tweaking weight paints and shape keys): It looks like you used a subdivision modifier and applied it. Do you have an older version before applying that modifier? Otherwise, try the Decimate modifier in "un-subdivide" mode and an even number of iterations.

Comment: @L0Lock No, sadly I don't. I'm doing this for my game in Unity, and I'm not that skilled at blender, I only know the basics. I didn't think to do all this.